# CSS dropdown menu not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Whenever I try to add drop down code to my Menu link i.e About, Portfolio, they just appear on rightside without appearing as dropdown.

Check the website at:

something must be conflicting in CSS.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: what do you want under About Us section

Comment: I want to add a dropdown menu under about menu item.

Comment: Also, close span tag in <a href="http://www.tastysnack.co.uk" id="home"><span>HOME<span></a>

Comment: that is not related to coding stuff..thats designing @tradyblix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use this way:

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
* {font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma;}
ul.nav {border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav li a {display: block; text-decoration: none; color: #333; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li:hover {border: 1px solid #666; border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav li a:hover {background: #ccc; border: 1px solid #999;}
ul.nav > li {display: inline-block; position: relative; border: 1px solid #fff;}
ul.nav > li ul {display: none; position: absolute; left: -1px; width: 150px; border: 1px solid #666; border-top-color: #fff; margin-top: 1px;}
ul.nav > li:hover ul {display: block;}
ul.nav > li ul li {display: block;} /* Vertical Menu */
ul.nav > li ul li {display: inline-block;} /* Horizontal Menu */
```

#### Fiddle:
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/ (Vertical Menu)
 http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/1/ (Horizontal Menu)